# 301 Redirect from main domain (www and non-www) to subdomain

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, http-status-code-301

I need to redirect from a main domain like mydomain.com or www.mydomain.com to sub.mydomain.com - and this needs to work for all requests, so mydomain.com/whatever goes to sub.mydomain.com/whatever.

I've tried this, which only works for non-www at the main domain:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://sub.mydomain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: I am more curious just for learning purposes than anything else but what is the benefit of this redirect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could condense them into a single rule as well:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://sub.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Mark's point about the `/` is an important consideration. Since you're defining the rule in `.htaccess` though, the input (and by association the captured backreference) will not start with a leading slash, so you actually do need an explicit one in this case (like you had).

Since we just want the whole path anyway, using `%{REQUEST_URI}` is more reliable in this sense because it will always have a leading slash, regardless of the context we're using the rule in.

Answer (score 2):

Also add:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.mydomain.com\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://sub.mydomain.com$1 [R=301,L]
```

One thing also to note is you likely don't want that last `/` in your `RewriteRule`, as it'll add two slashes to the redirected URL (e.g. `http://mydomain.com/foo.html` becomes `http://sub.mydomain.com//foo.html`).